# form data insert in database with one foreign key columns in php

Tags: php, database, insert, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert contact form into database.

1.) I am trying to insert contact form without foreign key working fine.

2.) But form data insert with other table foreign key columns not working.

`control.php`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
            {
                $co_name=$_REQUEST['co_name'];
                $co_email=$_REQUEST['co_email'];
                $co_subject=$_REQUEST['co_subject'];
                $co_comment=$_REQUEST['co_comment'];
                
                $data=array("co_name"=>$co_name,"co_email"=>$co_email,"co_subject"=>$co_subject,"co_comment"=>$co_comment);
                $res=$this->insert('customer_contact',$data);
                if($res)
                {
                    echo"sucess";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Wrong";
                }
            }
```

This is `model.php` code

```
<?php 

class model
{
    public $conn="";
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn=new MySQLi("localhost","root","mohit@75","new_healthy_life");
    }
    function select($tbl)
    {
        $sel="SELECT * FROM $tbl";
        $exc=$this->conn->query($sel);
        while($fetch=$exc->fetch_object())
        {
            $arr[]=$fetch;
        }
        return $arr;
    }
    function insert($tbl,$data)
    {
        $col_arr=array_keys($data);
        $col=implode(",",$col_arr);
        
        $value_arr=array_values($data);
        $value=implode("','",$value_arr);
        
        echo $insert="INSERT INTO `$tbl`($col) value('$value')";
        $exc=$this->conn->query($insert);
        
        return $exc;
    }
}
```

Below contact table image

[image]

My Actual question is form data how to insert with foreign key.

Show image :-

[image]

How to solve this...

Thanks ...

Comment: What error are you getting. also on this line 
$res=$this->insert('customer_contact',$data); $data doesn't seem to have cu_id.

Comment: `cu_id` is foreign key.And cu_id columns is another table

Comment: while inserting into your customer_contact table, cu_id I assume is you customer id. while inserting into your customer_contact table, you need to provide cu_id too.

Comment: i have try but showing this error https://prnt.sc/sbojut

Comment: the error clearly says cu_id is empty. answer by @Jaymin is correct. you may have to modify it according your table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just modify your insert function and return inserted id:

```
function insert($tbl,$data)
    {
        $col_arr=array_keys($data);
        $col=implode(",",$col_arr);

        $value_arr=array_values($data);
        $value=implode("','",$value_arr);

        echo $insert="INSERT INTO `$tbl`($col) value('$value')";
        $exc=$this->conn->query($insert);
        $last_id = $this->conn->insert_id;
        return $last_id;
    }
```

Now in your `control.php`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $co_name=$_REQUEST['co_name'];
    $co_email=$_REQUEST['co_email'];
    $co_subject=$_REQUEST['co_subject'];
    $co_comment=$_REQUEST['co_comment'];

    $data=array("co_name"=>$co_name,"co_email"=>$co_email,"co_subject"=>$co_subject,"co_comment"=>$co_comment);
    $res=$this->insert('customer_contact',$data);
    if($res)
    {
        //
        $data=array("foreignkey_col1"=>$foreignkey_col1_data,"foreign_key"=>$res);
        $res1=$this->insert('foreign_key_table',$data);
        if($res1)
        {
            //inserted into master table as well
        }
        else
        {
        //issue while inserting into master table
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong";
    }
}
```

I am not sure about your other table name of foreign key so I have just kept static and sample data but you see now `$res` will return inserted id and that you can use to insert into another table name as well by writing another insert query.